# Problematic question subtitles in exsheets

Tags: exsheets

I'm using the excellent `exsheets` package to write the problem sections of a book. Because I need titles for the questions, I'm using the `subtitle` functionality built in the package. So even though it does the job, there are two problems:

1. Subtitles don't have automatic line break.
2. Subtitles with commas or accents produce errors.

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{exsheets}
\SetupExSheets{
  headings = block-subtitle
}

\begin{document}

\begin{question}[subtitle=I'm trying to make a super long subtitle that extends way beyond the page's normal margins.]
First exercise.
\end{question}

\begin{question}[subtitle={Another subtitle, now with commas and áccents}]
Second exercise.
\end{question}
\end{document}
```

Problem no. 2 seems like the worst one. Loading `inputenc` with `utf8` doesn't fix it, but I discovered that enclosing the subtitle in brackets works, like I did in the MWE. Nevertheless, can it be done *without* the brackets?

I haven't been able to fix problem no. 1. I've tried `\newline`, double backslash, etc. Any ideas on how could I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Options and commas**

Since the optional argument to the `question` environment can be a comma separated list

```
[subtitle=Another subtitle, now with commas and áccents]
```

consists of two “options”:

- `subtitle=Another subtitle`
- `now with commas and áccents`

As you've found out yourself: if a option contains a comma, the argument *must* be placed in braces:

```
[subtitle={Another subtitle, now with commas and áccents}]
```

As far as the accent is concerned: that's a question of using the right input encoding. Using a unicode `á` and `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` will work nicely with pdflatex.

**Subtitles**

Subtitles are typeset in a horizontal box. Consequences are: no line breaks. A possible workaround would be a suitable redefinition of the `block-subtitle` instance using the `subtitle-pre-code` option in order to place the subtitle within a `\parbox`. Since the code following the pre-code is wrapped in braces this will work:

```
\DeclareInstance{exsheets-heading}{block-subtitle}{default}{
  join = {
    title[r,B]number[l,B](.333em,0pt) ;
    title[r,B]subtitle[l,B](1em,0pt) ;
    title[l,B]points[l,B](\linewidth+\marginparsep,0pt) ;
    main[l,T]title[l,T](0pt,0pt) ;
  } ,
  subtitle-pre-code = \parbox[t]{.8\linewidth}
}
```

The complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{exsheets}
\DeclareInstance{exsheets-heading}{block-subtitle}{default}{
  join = {
    title[r,B]number[l,B](.333em,0pt) ;
    title[r,B]subtitle[l,B](1em,0pt) ;
    title[l,B]points[l,B](\linewidth+\marginparsep,0pt) ;
    main[l,T]title[l,T](0pt,0pt) ;
  } ,
  subtitle-pre-code = \parbox[t]{.8\linewidth}
}
\SetupExSheets{
  headings = block-subtitle
}

\begin{document}

\begin{question}[subtitle={I'm trying to make a super long subtitle that
    extends way beyond the page's normal margins.}]
  First exercise. More text
\end{question}

\begin{question}[subtitle={Another subtitle, now with commas and áccents}]
  Second exercise.
\end{question}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent! Placing subtitles in parbox could be the default implementation for future releases... or is there a disadvantage I don't see?

Comment: There is one problem: knowing how much space is left to the end of the column in order to give a suitable width to the `\parbox`. It is solvable, though :)

Comment: Ah yes, I see it. In fact, in my book's current configuration the margin is a bit smaller than the one you set up on your solution. Anyway, nice work with exsheets!

Answer (score 2):

A dirty trick:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{exsheets}
\SetupExSheets{
  headings = block-subtitle
}

\begin{document}

\begin{question}[subtitle=\parbox[t][-1ex]{0.8\hsize}{%
                 I'm trying to make a super long subtitle that extends way beyond the page's normal margins.}]
\bigskip
First exercise.
\end{question}

\begin{question}[subtitle={Another subtitle, now with commas and áccents}]
Second exercise.
\end{question}
\end{document}
```

You need to compile at least twice that new formatting overtake the control. The width of `\parbox` you select according to your needs. 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Dirty trick for the 2nd problem (also compiled twice):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{exsheets}
\SetupExSheets{
  headings = block-subtitle
}


\begin{question}[subtitle=Another subtitle{,} now with commas and \'{a}ccents]
Second exercise.
\end{question}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Rather than placing the comma within braces you should surround the whole option with braces as the OP has done in his question. Then the outer set of braces will be removed when the option is processed whereas here the comma will stay in braces which may have effects on kerning...

Comment: I agree with @clemens. I think the reason why is nicely explained in his answer.